# How to crawl specific data on a dynamic webpage using phantomJS?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, web-crawler

I know i am asking a very general question but I am really really new to javascript and phantomJS. I am trying to build a web crawler to crawl specific information on a web page.

Right now my code looks like this and it gives me everything on the page.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

    page.open ('https://www.lennar.com/new-homes/washington/seattle', function(status) {
      console.log("status: " + status);

      if (status === "success"){
      //  page.render('example.png');
        console.log(page.plainText);
      }
      phantom.exit();
    });
```

Right now it gives me everything, but I want the bolded words on this page
https://www.lennar.com/new-homes/washington/seattle

IF YOU click open the link
I want to crawl the bolded black words with the location
So basically I want to print :
Canton Highlands

Canton Park South
Canton Ridge 
Christy's Crossing
Eagle Glen
.....

I am really clueless. Any suggestion will help? Where should I start to look at?

Comment: Have you read any tutorials on web scraping? What do you think the next step you should take now that you can open the target page?

Comment: One way is with jQuery, Open that page in chrome and paste this into the console: `jQuery('h1 a').text()`